# Table inside a Table in SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, multiple-tables

I am actually making an app where I had made a table which contains details for no. Of stores. Now I want to create table for each store which will details of things/products.
Now the problem is list of stores is not fixed user can add as much store as he wants thus for each new store I want to make new table programmatically.

I have implemented store table with standard technique with fixed table with predefined name and colomns.

I am a newbie to Android please guide.

Comment: Maybe start by writing a title that makes sense... *Table inside a Table* makes no sense, and it's not even related to your question.

Comment: The concept of *table inside table* does not exist in SQLite. Start by studying about relational databases and sql. Just google it.

Comment: Thanks for encouraging!

Comment: Google for `relations in RDBMS`. It actually takes just a table with the Stores and another one with the Details. In the Stores one, just add as many records as many details that store has. Then a simple JOIN will do.

Answer (score 3):

To follow normalisation and to reduce overheads, it doesn't look as though a table for the other store information is necessary. Just have a table with the Store details, as those details will be static/specific to a store.

However, if you have a table for each user and the user will have a variable list of stores, then you would likely have a table for the users and then a mapping/reference/link table for what becomes a many to many relationship (i.e. a user can have many stores and a store can be referenced/linked to many users).

For example you could have the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stores;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_store_reference;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user_name TEXT, user_email, TEXT, user_password TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stores(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, store_name TEXT, store_address TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_store_reference (user_reference INTEGER, store_reference INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(user_reference,store_reference));

INSERT INTO users (user_name,user_email,user_password) VALUES
    ('Fred','fred@xmail.moc','1234567890'), -- will be id `
    ('Bert','bert@noemail.net','0987654321'), -- will be id 2
    ('Mary','mary@hotmail.com','11111111') -- will be id 3
;
INSERT INTO Stores (store_name,store_address) VALUES
    ('The Corner Store','1 The Corner, Squaretown'), -- will be id 1
    ('Smiths','10 Somewhere Street, Noweheretown'), -- will be id 2
    ('Cottons','4 Wool Street, Fabrictown'), -- will be id 3
    ('Stringers','114 High Street, Noweheretown') -- will be id 4
;
INSERT INTO user_store_reference VALUES
    (1,2), -- Fred has store Smiths
    (1,4), -- Fred also has store Stringers
    (3,1), -- Mary has store The Corner Store
    (3,2), -- Mary also has store Smiths
    (3,3), -- Mary also has store Cottons
    (2,2), -- Bert has store Smiths
    (2,3), -- Bert has store Cottons
    (2,1), -- Bert has store The Corner Store
    (2,4) -- Bert has store Stringers
;

SELECT user_name, count() AS store_count, group_concat(store_name,' - ') 
FROM users 
JOIN user_store_reference ON user_reference = users._id 
JOIN stores ON stores._id = store_reference
GROUP BY users._id ORDER BY count() ASC
;
```

The query at the end would result in an overview of the number of stores per user with a list of those stores (as an example of how you link/map/reference aka **JOIN** the tables to get results):-

[image]

### The equivalent on Android

The above could be translated to Android using the following code :-

**The Database Helper Class `DBHelper.java`**

A common way of using SQLite on Android is to utilise a subclass of the **SQLiteOpenHelper** class. The following is an example of such a class (frequently termed the Database Helper) :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "StoresAppDB";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TB_USERS = "users";
    public static final String TB_STORES = "stores";
    public static final String TB_USERSTOREMAP = "user_store_reference";

    public static final String COL_USERS_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_USERS_NAME = "user_name";
    public static final String COL_USERS_EMAIL = "user_email";
    public static final String COL_USERS_PASSWORD = "user_password";

    public static final String COL_STORES_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_STORES_NAME = "store_name";
    public static final String COL_STORES_ADDRESS = "store_address";

    public static final String COL_USERSTOREMAP_USERREF = "user_reference";
    public static final String COL_USERSTOREMAP_STOREREF = "store_reference";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String tblcrt_base = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ";
        String id_col_def = " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ";
        String users_crtsql = tblcrt_base + TB_USERS + "(" +
                COL_USERS_ID + id_col_def +
                COL_USERS_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COL_USERS_EMAIL + " TEXT," +
                COL_USERS_PASSWORD + " TEXT " +
                ")";
        String stores_crtsql = tblcrt_base + TB_STORES + "(" +
                COL_STORES_ID + id_col_def +
                COL_STORES_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COL_STORES_ADDRESS + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        String userstore_crtsql = tblcrt_base + TB_USERSTOREMAP + "(" +
                COL_USERSTOREMAP_USERREF + " INTEGER, " +
                COL_USERSTOREMAP_STOREREF + ", " +
                " PRIMARY KEY (" +
                COL_USERSTOREMAP_USERREF +
                "," +
                COL_USERSTOREMAP_STOREREF +
                ")" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(users_crtsql);
        db.execSQL(stores_crtsql);
        db.execSQL(userstore_crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addUser(String name, String email, String password) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_USERS_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_USERS_EMAIL,email);
        cv.put(COL_USERS_PASSWORD,password);
        return mDB.insert(TB_USERS,null,cv);
    }

    public long addStore(String name, String address) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_STORES_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_STORES_ADDRESS,address);
        return mDB.insert(TB_STORES,null,cv);
    }

    public long addUserStoreMapping(long user, long store) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_USERSTOREMAP_USERREF,user);
        cv.put(COL_USERSTOREMAP_STOREREF,store);
        return mDB.insert(TB_USERSTOREMAP,null,cv);
    }

    /*
        SELECT users._id, user_name, count() AS store_count, user_name||' has stores '||group_concat(store_name,' - ')
        FROM users
        JOIN user_store_reference ON user_reference = users._id
        JOIN stores ON stores._id = store_reference
        GROUP BY users._id ORDER BY count() ASC
        ;
     */
    public static final String DCOL_COUNT = "store_count";
    public static final String DCOL_USERANDSTORES = "user_and_stores";
    public Cursor getUserStoreUsage() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                TB_USERS + "." + COL_USERS_ID,
                COL_USERS_NAME,
                "count() AS " + DCOL_COUNT,
                COL_USERS_NAME + "||' has stores '||group_concat(" + COL_STORES_NAME + ",' - ') AS " + DCOL_USERANDSTORES
        };
        String tables =
                TB_USERS +
                        " JOIN " + TB_USERSTOREMAP + " ON " + COL_USERSTOREMAP_USERREF + "=" + TB_USERS + "." + COL_USERS_ID +
                        " JOIN " + TB_STORES + " ON " + TB_STORES + "." + COL_STORES_ID + "=" + COL_USERSTOREMAP_STOREREF
                ;
        return mDB.query(tables,columns,null,null,TB_USERS+"."+COL_USERS_ID,null,"count() ASC");
    }
}
```

This includes :-

- Creation of the tables when the database is created.
- Methods to facilitate adding rows
- A method `getUserStoreUsage()` to return a Cursor with user/store information (that will be listed via a listview). This is similar to the query above.

  - Note as a Cursor Adapter is being utilised a row named **`_id`** (hence the use of **`BaseColumns._ID`** which equates to **`_id`**)

**The invoking activity `MainActivity.java`**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DBHelper mDBhlpr;
ListView mLV;
Cursor mCsr;
SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLV = this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mDBhlpr = new DBHelper(this);
    addSomeData();
    mCsr = mDBhlpr.getUserStoreUsage();
    mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            mCsr,
            new String[]{DBHelper.DCOL_USERANDSTORES,DBHelper.DCOL_COUNT},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},
            0
    );
    mLV.setAdapter(mSCA);
}

private void addSomeData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDBhlpr.getWritableDatabase();
    if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,DBHelper.TB_USERS) < 1) {
        mDBhlpr.addUser("Fred","fred@fredmail.com","1234567890");
        mDBhlpr.addUser("Bert","bert@bertmail.com","0987654321");
        mDBhlpr.addUser("Mary","mary@marymail.com","1111");
    }
    if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,DBHelper.TB_STORES) < 1) {
        mDBhlpr.addStore("The Corner Store","1 The Corner, Squaretown");
        mDBhlpr.addStore("Smiths","10 Somewhere Street, Noweheretown");
        mDBhlpr.addStore("Cottons","4 Wool Street, Fabrictown");
        mDBhlpr.addStore("Stringers","114 High Street, Noweheretown");
    }
    if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,DBHelper.TB_USERSTOREMAP) < 1) {
        mDBhlpr.addUserStoreMapping(1,2);
        mDBhlpr.addUserStoreMapping(1,4);
        mDBhlpr.addUserStoreMapping(3,1);
        mDBhlpr.addUserStoreMapping(3,2);
        mDBhlpr.addUserStoreMapping(3,3);
        mDBhlpr.addUserStoreMapping(2,2);
        mDBhlpr.addUserStoreMapping(2,3);
        mDBhlpr.addUserStoreMapping(2,1);
        mDBhlpr.addUserStoreMapping(2,4);
    }
}
```

}

#### Result :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to better understand the relationship of your tables between each other.

My SQL-fu is a bit rusty but here is a dirty quick example of multiple stores db.

So you have your stores table where you add the ID and the store name(which I forgot to add).

Then you have your details table (where you have the details for that store)

And you connect both of these tables with the middle table which is called StoreDetails.

If you want to learn in deep how to break many to many relationships in databases a quick google search will bring up a lot of examples.

[image]

Comment: A ***one to many*** relation is enough. No need for the look-up table.

Comment: It might be, as I said my SQL-fu is quite rusty :)